# how to write a simple aggregation query in mongo db 2.0.6 with json API

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Just started mongo and started having issue with querying already. i have a collection called 'externalTransaction' and i want to write a equivalent of this mysql query:

```
select transactionCode, 
       sum(amount) as totalSum, 
       count(amount) as totalCount 
from externalTransaction 
where transactioncode in ('aa','bb','cc') 
group by sum(amount)
```

below is my attempt:

```
{
 "collectionName": "externalTransaction",
  sort: {transactionCode:-1},
  query: {this._id: {$in:['aa','bb','cc']}},
  mapReduce:{
   'map': 'function(){

        emit(this.transactionCode, this.amount);

   }',
 'reduce': 'function(key, values){
    var result = {count: 0, sum: 0.0};

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result.count++
       result.sum += value.amount;
    });
    return result;
 }',
   'out' : 'sumAmount'
 }
```

}

the above query give me a result set looking like this:

```
_id     value.count        value.sum
ct      2.0                NaN
bb      40.0           NaN
fg      71.0           NaN
fd      36.0           NaN
sd      5.0                NaN
as      4.0            NaN
aa      71.0           NaN
df      4.0                NaN
cc      10.0               NaN
```

From the documentation with the version `2.0.6` i can't use the `aggregation framework` just yet so how to handle simple queries like mine in mongo. thanks for reading and excuse the triviality of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your `map` and `reduce` functions. First, in `map` you emit a simple number, and in reduce you try to take `amount` of a number. I bet, it doesn't have that property. Second, outputs of `map` and `reduce` must be uniform, because `reduce` is supposed to be runnable over partially reduced results. Try these functions:

```
var map = function() {
  emit(this.transactionCode, {sum: this.amount, count: 1})
}

var reduce = function(k, vals) {
  var result = {sum: 0, count: 0};

  vals.forEach(function(v) {
    result.sum += v.sum;
    result.count += v.count;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: nice thanks for the answer. i think with your suggestion i got something working.but am wondering why the filter isn't working. it's still picking every transaction. have i done anything wrong there too?

Comment: @blacksensei: yeah, it looks odd. Shouldn't it be `query: {transactionCode: {$in:['aa','bb','cc']}}`?

Comment: changed it to `query: {transactionCode: {$in:['aa','bb','cc']}}` but still pulling everything. :(

Comment: How do you run this exactly? And where did you get this syntax from?

Comment: Look at the examples here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/jstests/mr1.js. Try to make it work in the mongo shell.

Comment: hey @sergio, i put an if clause before the emit function in the map function. that seems to work for now. am cheking your link now. thanks .i mark this as solved thanks

Comment: am runing it from ireport which uses json style. the thing is from my ubuntu terminal a lot of things works. but when it comes to json it's kinda complex.since the final query is to be used by ireport i would rather still with this gui to write and verify the query

Comment: Well, if mongodb doesn't work - it's one thing. If it's some 3rd party tool - it's completely different. You should have mentioned this earlier, I'd send you to their support :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13067/discussion-between-black-sensei-and-sergio-tulentsev)